# Data binding could not find identifier "view"

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
<data>
    <variable
        name = "registrationViewModel"
        type="com.android.freecommunity.ui.auth.AuthViewModel"/>
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".ui.auth.Register">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="352dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/intro_background" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_layout_container"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edit_text"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fullname"
            android:text="@={registrationViewModel.fullName}"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edit_text"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email Address"
            android:text="@={registrationViewModel.email}"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edge_button"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:onClick="@={(view)-> registrationViewModel.onRegisterButtonClicked(view)}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Already a member"
            android:textColor="@color/not_a_member"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:onClick="@{registrationViewModel::onLogin}"
            android:textColor="@color/not_a_member"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Forget Password ?"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="81dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:translationY="-10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_holder"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edit_text"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Phone"
            android:text="@={registrationViewModel.phoneNumber}"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edit_text"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calendar"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="DOB"
            android:text="@={registrationViewModel.date_of_birth}"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edit_text"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/address"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Home Address"
            android:text="@={registrationViewModel.address}"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="345dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edit_text"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:entries="@array/work_category_array"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:entries="@array/daily_payment_plan"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thats my xml

```
 fun onRegisterButtonClicked(view: View){


    authListener?.onStarted()

    if (fullName.isNullOrEmpty()){
        authListener?.onFailure("FullName is required")
        return
    }
    if (email.isNullOrEmpty()){
        authListener?.onFailure("Email is required")
        return
    }

    if (password.isNullOrEmpty()){
        authListener?.onFailure("Password is required")
        return
    }
```

This is where im trying to use the function inside my view model, i've tried all other way to do the onclick in my xml, but i keep getting errors. 
[please ignore]

This is where im trying to use the function inside my view model, i've tried all other way to do the onclick in my xml, but i keep getting errors. 
This is where im trying to use the function inside my view model, i've tried all other way to do the onclick in my xml, but i keep getting errors.

Comment: please add your entire layout

Comment: @Zain i have added the whole layout

Answer (score 19):

You must import View first. Add the following to the top of your layout:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

More details :https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports

Answer (score 6):

add this to your build.gradle :

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Comment: `buildFeatures { dataBinding true }` according to this: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/databinding

Answer (score 0):

So since you didn't provide the error log you get, I will try to add potential cause as mentioned in the question title

> Data binding could not find identifier “view”

In your layout you need to remove `view` from the button click callback and the equal sign is useless, so replace below

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="@={(view)-> registrationViewModel.onRegisterButtonClicked(view)}" />
```

with

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="@{()-> registrationViewModel.onRegisterButtonClicked()}" />
```

or you also use

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="@{registrationViewModel::onRegisterButtonClicked}" />
```

I omitted other attributes, so keep them unchanged.

Comment: i get:  cannot find method onRegisterButtonClicked() in class com.android.freecommunity.ui.auth.AuthViewModel

Comment: Is this method in your viewmodel or activity class?

Comment: the last method gives no error, but doesn't trigger the onRegisterButtonClicked() method

Comment: the method is in my viewmodel

Comment: this method should be in the activity class instead of the viewmodel, because your view model should never have any view references, it just should handle data related to the views, so you need to move this method to the activity class; and create a  new <variable> in your <layout> for this activity class; say you name this variable as `MyActivity`; so then call `android:onClick="@{MyActivity::onRegisterButtonClicked }"`

Comment: @HUSSENIABDULHAKEEM Do you get app crashes? if so please update with the logcat .. if not, then you need to do some debuging